# I want to save the result of the model.predict() function in pixmap

Tags: yolo, predict, pyqt6

I'm trying to recognize images. I use PyQt6 for my gui. Here is part of my code:

```
FileModelPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "WorkFile\\best.pt")
model = YOLO(FileModelPath)
img = Image.open(Ui_MainWindow.FILEPATH)
predictions  = model.predict(img, show = True, classes=[0,1], project="C:/photo", hide_labels = False, hide_conf = False, conf=float(0.8),save = False, line_thickness=1)
```

I understand that model.predict() can save the image to "C:/photo", but can I somehow convert the result of this function to pixmap to insert into label?

I tried to use something like this, it seems to even work without errors

```
FileModelPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "WorkFile\\best.pt")
model = YOLO(FileModelPath)
img = Image.open(Ui_MainWindow.FILEPATH)
predictions = model.predict(img, show = True, classes=[0,1], project="C:/foto", hide_labels = False, hide_conf = False, conf=float(0.8),save = False, line_thickness=1)
predictions = np.array(predictions)
image = QImage(predictions.data, predictions.shape[1], predictions.shape[0], QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
self.labelFoto.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

but in labelFoto I get nothing